# Finding the Minimum path

Tags: geometry

**Question :-** An ant is 4 m away from a sugar cube and 5 points A to E are marked between the sugar cube and the ant.  An ant repellant is placed exactly at point C and if the ant comes closer than 1 m of the repellant, it dies.  Minimum distance that the ant has to travel to get to the sugar cube will be ?

---

**My attempt:-**

[image]
According to my diagram I am getting $2+√2$ m , but it isn't correct, how to proceed in that case ?

Comment: draw the curve that is $1$ m away from C, what kind of curve is that? Can you find a shorter path?

Comment: As the ant is walking "up" along your path, show that it dies because it is closer than 1m to the repellant. Hence it cannot complete your path.

Comment: They already know the answer by experience. Ask them :)

Comment: @CalvinLin is it fine now ?

Comment: @Fin27 Is what fine? I don't see any substantive edits that you made. $\quad$ Your ant will still die if it walks diagonally from B. The only line from B that stays 1m away from C, is the vertical line (IE Tangent to the circle). Any slanted line will thus intersect the circle and hence the ant is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Only a visual clue, no explanation.

[image]

Comment: Yes, $(2*√3)$+$(π/3)$, how did you come up with the idea of a circle :O

Comment: Did you read @NotaChoice's comment?

Answer (score 0):

Explaining @Narasimham's answer, first you get the idea of the circle because 1m about point C the ant cannot enter. So the ant must have to travel along the circular path. But this is not the "shortest" approach the ant can take.
[image: Diagram]
So now we can take a point P on the circle (having a mirror point P' due to symmetry) and then try to find out the distance of it.
Now using cosine rule we can write AP in terms of AC and PC and angle $\theta$, as $AP^2 = 4+1-2*2cos(\pi/2-\theta/2) = 5 - 4sin(\theta/2)$
So now $AP = BP' = \sqrt{5-4sin(\theta/2)} $
Now total distance covered by the ant can be written as: $2\sqrt{5-4sin(\theta/2)}+\theta$
You can prove using Differentiation that this attains its maximum value when $\theta = \pi/3$ in the range $(0,\pi/2)$
So the max distance is $2\sqrt{3}+\pi/3$

Comment: The path should be tangential else ant would perish. Right triangles each side have 30,60 degrees. Central angle in circle  60[degrees.j

Comment: @Narasimham Why should path be "strictly" tangential to the circle? For the shortest path I agree that you will end up getting it as tangenetial, but for a random path, it need not be.

Comment: I am saying the same thing. By drawing tangent as shown we have minimum total path length.  Each of the three angles $  ACP, PC P',P'C B$ equals to $ 60^{\circ}  $

Comment: If we can say so, often the physical intuitive experiences come first and then explanations follow.